# xdotool: resize terminator to a particular number of rows and columns

Tags: bash, terminal, resize, xdotool

I am using archlinux and have terminator (terminal) installed.

Now i want to use xdotool to resize the terminal from a script.

But i want to resize the terminator terminal to a particular number of rows.

Curently i know how to set the terminator size using xdotool:

```
windowid=$(xdotool search  --desktop 0 --class Terminator | awk 'END{print}'); 
xdotool windowsize ${windowid} width height
```

But i am looking something for

```
windowid=$(xdotool search  --desktop 0 --class Terminator | awk 'END{print}'); 
xdotool windowsize ${windowid} cols rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Try resizing with wmctrl. I make an alias for a standard sized terminator window. (using BASH, and put it in ~/.bashrc)

```
alias stdwin='wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 1,0,40,810,600'
```

You can install wmctrl (I'm using Debian derived Bunsen) with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```